# How do I edit a section in WordPress to make each row have 4 columns only?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want help in correcting this problem. I have a WordPress section with 4 columns. I just want when I add any other column that is not in the same row, I want it to be in a new row. Very briefly, I want one row to contain only 4 columns. No more how do I do this in Custome CSS

[image]

This is the CSS code that I wrote, but it is not working:

**.products** : It is the big diva that contains 4 cards.

**.column** : It is a class of cards, meaning that each card is in its own class name column.

```
.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.column {
  flex: 25px;
  max-width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use `justify-content:space-around;` for the parent and for the `width` each `column` use between `20` to `25` we can achieve that.
Also for the vertical space we can give a bit of vertical margin to look better
So you can do it this way:

```css
.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1000px;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
.column {
  width:21%;
  max-width: 25%;
  background: gray;
  margin:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='products'>
  <div class='column'>1</div>
  <div class='column'>2</div>
  <div class='column'>3</div>
  <div class='column'>4</div>
  <div class='column'>5</div>
  <div class='column'>6</div>
  <div class='column'>7</div>
</div>
```